# Puzzle: Planar configuration of straight connecting lines

Tags: geometry, coordinates, lines, planar-graph

Puzzle :  Given an even number of points in general positions on the plane (that is, no three points co-linear), can you partition the points into pairs and connect the two points of each pair with a single straight line such that the straight lines do not overlap?

My Solution : One simple approach (that seems just too simple).

Start with the point with left-most x-coordinate and then draw a line to the next least left-most x-coordinate. Then find the next least pair of points and connect and so on!

Is this correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just tried it! That's one of the solutions!